# Adding Numbers in a DOB?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I make it add the numbers separately to the user's input?  for example:  120409 = 25  I am new to python. Why isn't the total working?? Right now nothing is  printed, is there something wrong with my indentation?

```
    me = int(input("enter your dob 230478"))

    def dob(me):
        dob = []
        count = 0
        me = str(me)
        for i in range(len(me)):
            dob.append(me[i])
        for i in range(len(dob)):
            dob[i] = int(dob[i])
            count += dob[i]
        total = count + me
    print(dob,me)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
usrInp = str(input("enter your dob 230478: "))

def method1(usrInp):
  count = 0
  for digit in usrInp:
    count = count + int(digit)
  print(count)

method1(usrInp)
```